# How to calculate the circularity of a occluded Circle

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to find a way to calculate how circular a image mask is for a object that is partly occluded. There is room for error so it doesn't have to be extremely accurate

I've tried implementing hough transform but it was creating too many false positives.

*Image example*
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post original image, please?

Comment: sorry, I'm only allowed to share the mask

Answer (score 1):

With such occlusion, defining the circularity is challenging. An option is to obtain a robust fit by an ellipse and consider the ratio of the axis. (In this case, about 1.05.)

[image]

An approach to obtain the fit can be by RANSAC. But as you need five points, the number of drawings can be huge. You can reduce that number by segmenting the outline in smooth sections and sampling inside the longest sections.

Comment: @ib-student: sorry, no, this belongs to commercial software. If you want to measure circularity, this perforce means that a circle fit is not appropriate, and you can't determine a center so easily.

Comment: @ib-student: why do you insist and ignore my comments ? By the way, the tool I used for the sake of illustration is interactive, not an automated solution.

Comment: @ib-student: why do you insist and ignore my comments. We can help you. But sorry, you are not allowed to get source code from Yves Daoust.

Comment: @YvesDaoust My bad, my wifi at the time wasn't working properly so I thought my message didn't send. I did take your comments into consideration.

Comment: @ib-student: you can estimate the local center of curvature by taking triples of nearby points, and from there estimate the *evolute* of the outline. This should help you find an approximate circle center. The triples should not be too close, or accuracy will be low, but not too distant or they will overshoot smooth sections.

Comment: @ib-student: how do you define circularity ? Or asked differently, what use is it to know a circularity ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I would say something with high circularity to be an object with uniform radii throughout?

Comment: @ib-student: this is quite insufficient.

Comment: @YvesDaoust then what would you say defines circularity?

Comment: @YvesDaoust in this scenario the mask represents coiled metal. So high circularity would mean the metal is uniform and can be heated uniformly

Comment: I cannot imagine a relation between circularity and metal uniformness !? Can you show a "non-circular" coil ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust My apologies, I talked to the site engineer today and it isn't about uniformness. When the coil is oval or triangular(can happen during the wrapping process)  it tends to bounce. This can harm the equipment and can throw off the position for the next step. I'm not allowed to share image data but imagine trying to squish a roll of tape(circle to oval). thats the shape we don't want.

Comment: No image, no good answer. (Not allowed is a little laughable; there is no secret in showing a coil, even with anomalies.)

Comment: Let me try talking with my team lead, if he lets me. I'll update the question.

Comment: You can contact me privately (see profile), I have some experience with coil inspection.